# Change object key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this following map over an object with an array of objects

```
Object.values(props.roleRateOptions).map(el => {
  el.push(shift.roleRate);
  return el;
})
```

It will return into an array  of objects like this

```
[ {id:1},{id:2},{label:3} ]
```

The problem is when i `push(shift.roleRate)` it has a value called `label` instead of `id`, how can i change it to `id`? Or any work around, maybe i could assign a new value of id if i cannot change this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can re-map the objects in array:

```js
var data = [{id:1},{id:2},{label:3}];

var res = data.map(x => ({ id: x.id || x.label}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rename that value in an IIFE:

```
 el.push((({ label, ...rest }) => ({ id: label, ...rest }))(shift.roleRate));
```

Or just copy that property before:

```
 shift.roleRate.id = shift.roleRate.label;
 el.push(shift.roleRate);
```